# Visual Studio 2010 RC - Is there a VirtualPC or VMWare image available?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to try the latest VS2010 RC. But I am not very comfortable installing it on my production machine. 
For Beta2 there were VirtualPC images available at Microsoft which I cannot find for the RC.

Did I overlook them or doesn't MS provide them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not going to be a VM of this it looks like since RTM is in just over a month now.  I guess they figured they'll get enough feedback on speed improvements from non-VM users that it's not worth it to support them in the RC?

I don't know the exact reasoning, but I wouldn't expect one to appear before RTM.

However, that's not to say you can't load up a VM and just install the VS 2010 RC ISO ([found here!](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=457bab91-5eb2-4b36-b0f4-d6f34683c62a&displaylang=en)) on it.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. Then I'll try to make some room on my VM.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e13b15a-fd74-4cd7-b53e-bdf9456855bd&displaylang=en